# How to access the elements of other html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access the elements(by id) of body of other html page having same domain. Can it be possible?
Which function should I use?

Comment: Are you looking to getElementById?

Comment: Please be more specific about exactly what you are trying to do. Question can be interpreted several different ways. Intent of `access` is not very clear

Comment: Separately, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [*How do I ask a good question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: are you talking about iframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using AJAX, and you wanna use **Loading Page Fragments** in [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

In this case, the accessing page will have `#result` as the element's `id`. And the new page, which you said has the location of `ajax/test.html`. In that, the element with `#container` will be loaded in the `#result` of the calling page.

The rules for using this:

1. Both the calling page and callee page should be on the same domain.
2. If on different domain, it should have the headers: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: Thank you...!!! this is what I was looking for.